# JBehave results displayed on a webpage

Tags: jbehave

I have been working on a project that lets me test the behaviours of my companies webpage.

I have written an API and the testcase I am working on runs through JUnitRunner and the test passes.

The next step is to get the results displayed on a webpage, oes anyone know what plugin I need to get the JBehave results in HTML format or as a file.

I know I should be posting my code but there is no problems with the code, I just need the output in a different formatt.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the HTML output you need to make sure that you are generating the views with STATS and HTML output.

In MostUsefulConfiguration, add

```
    .useStoryReporterBuilder(
        new StoryReporterBuilder()
            .withReporters(new MyStoryReporter())
            .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML, Format.STATS)
```

In the Embedder method add

```
    embedder = configuredEmbedder();
    embedder
         .embedderControls()
         .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
```

This should be all you need to do to get HTML output.

We wanted more information than is provided in the default output so we created a new StoryReporter class to capture the additional data and '@Override' the existing methods where appropriate.  The new reporter class also needs to be added to the mostUseFulConfiguration

```
    .useStoryReporterBuilder(
        new StoryReporterBuilder()
            .withReporters(new MyStoryReporter())
```

We also needed to amend or create a new Freemarker template (jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl) to actually get it to write out the new data from the new story reporter class into an HTML file.  I am not going to provide an example here.  Please read the Freemarker documentation which is very good.

Answer (score 0):

check the reporting setup at JBehave's [site](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/reporting-stories.html).

and check the examples source code [here](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/tree/master/examples). almost all examples is reporting to html and others.